# Catel MVVM Structure

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I have a simple WPF Application and I used Catel (3.5) framework for using MVVM.
The Default structure for Catel in visual studio is:

```
Solution:
  Project:
    FolderView
    FolderViewModel
    FolderModel
```

I want to change the structure to

```
Solution:
  ProjectView
  ProjectViewModel
  ProjectModel
```

in this way I completely separate M-VM-V and I add reference.

I Understand that Catel scans the project automatically to find the Viewmodels if the naming convention are respected.

I can not make this work on the second structure, any advice will be pretreated.

**EDIT** 1:
I have added the following code in App.xaml.cs

```
var viewModelLocator = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IViewModelLocator>();
viewModelLocator.NamingConventions.Add("CatelV2ViewModel.ViewModels.[VW]ViewModel");
```

This does not work for me, and I have No Idea why. Im sure that My assembly name is correct AND I end my class name with *ViewModel*.

**EDIT** 2:
The application Works if I add the following code:

```
viewModelLocator.Register(typeof(MainWindow), typeof(MainWindowViewModel));
```

But I still want to know why it dosent work when I add a NamingConvention.

Comment: Why you want to have the ProjectView folder 2 times? I am missing a Viewmodel folder. or was that just a typo

Comment: @BartTeunissen Sorry about that, I have edit the structure. it was just a mistake.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use the catel framework? and not just stick to developing mvvm wise code on normal vs?

Comment: Im goning to work on a relatively large project and I need a solid framework to work on and I think Catel match my needs.

Comment: Clear as a daisy, but in that case, i cannot help you with your question. I can only help you with mvvm not with the framework ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catel has a lot of different naming conventions that are being used. Mostly it does this by checking the /Views, /ViewModels, /Models in the same project.

For more information about naming conventions in Catel, visit the documentation:

https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Naming+conventions

You probably want to customize the [ViewLocator](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/ViewLocator) and [ViewModelLocator](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/ViewModelLocator).

Comment: Thx for the reply. I still have a problem to solve the naming convention. I have Update the Code, if you have time to look at it.

Comment: Yes, you should not register types manually because you probably just want it to go through naming conventions. What you can try is to call LogManager.RegisterDebugListener() to check what the output windows says. It might give you some hints.

Comment: I've been working with this all day without any luck. if you have a very small and simple example which i can follow will be great.

Comment: Please create an issue at https://catelproject.atlassian.net/ and I will make it work.

Comment: I have created an issue at [link](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-53). This is a very simple example probably easy for you to solv. I want to thanks you for your time in advance.

Comment: It was a combination of the assembly not being loaded into the appdomain (no types being used => .NET does not load it). See issue at the above link for an example and the fix.